# Extract default value from json schema

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to create a json from a json schema using default value provided in the schema
so basically i want that a json like this

```json
{
    "type" : "object",
    "properties": {
        "string": {
            "type" : "ingeger",
            "default" : "the default string"
        },
        "number": {
            "type" : "number",
            "default" : 1
        },
        "object": {
            "type" : "object",
            "properties" : {
                "string": {
                    "type" : "ingeger",
                    "default" : "the default string 2"
                },
                "number": {
                    "type" : "number",
                    "default" : 2
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

end up like this

```json
{
  "string": "the default string",
  "number": 1,
  "object": {
    "string": "the default string 2",
    "number": 2
  }
}
```

When i saw this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60940893/15261387 i thought it would be easy to adapt this for my current problem but after many many try, I have to face the facts that i don't understand anything to the jq language/syntax

Answer (score 4):

You can use `map_values` on the `.properties` object The function returns the object back, selecting the field value given as part of the expression.

```
jq '.properties | map_values(.default)'
```

Comment: This is really nice, but it only solve one part of the problem, how can this be recursively performed for a json schema with nested object?

Comment: @LeeManGuard: You should've posted such a nested JSON into the question in the first place. Do update your real example, I'll try to modify my answer

Comment: i updated the json, i try something like this
def item:
  if .properties[].type != "object" then .properties | map_values(.default)
  else .properties[] | item end;
item

but it's not working at all